# Integer changing its own value in Visual Studio 2012 c++

Tags: c++, random, integer, default-value

the size variable of this class is set in the constructor to zero. it is only incremented or decremented when you add an item to the array or remove one, and in the case so cleaving in half, the size is cut to 1/2 capacity.

however, my size variable seems to run away, and randomly becomes random numbers, that are like 516846 which is not in the scope of the size that it was set to. I checked and followed my program through, and can not find anything that changes the size, and I know the size and capacity are being set upon construction.

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename ItemType>
class Node 
    {
    private:
        ItemType* items;
        int size;
        int capacity;

    public:
        Node* nextNode;
        Node* prevNode;

        Node(Node* pNode, Node* nNode, int limit)
        {
            prevNode = pNode;
            nextNode = nNode;
            capacity = limit;
            size = 0;

            if(capacity != 0)
                items = new ItemType[capacity];

            cout << "Node() capcity = " << capacity << " size = " << size << endl;
        };

        ~Node(void){};

        int getSize()
        {
            return size;
        };

        void addItem(int index, ItemType item)
        {
            cout << "node->addItem" << endl;
            for(int i = (getSize() - 1); i >= index; i--)
            {
                items[i + 1] = items[i];
            }
            items[index] = item;
            size ++;
        };
        void addItem(ItemType item)
        {
            cout << "node->addItem" << endl;
            items[getSize()] = item;
            size ++;
        };

        void deleteItem(int index)
        {
            cout << "node->deleteItem index = " << index << endl;

            for(int i = index; i < (getSize() - 1); i++)
            {
                items[i] = items[i+1];
            }
            size --;
        };


        void cleaveInHalf()
        {
            cout << "node->cleaveInHalf" << endl;
            size = capacity/2;
        };

        bool isFull()
        {
            return ((getSize() >= capacity) ? true : false);
        };

    };
```

when the isFull() function is called i get the error "Access violation reading location 0x00000004." and size is some weird number like 51515615.

```
    void insert(int index, const ItemType& item) 
    {
        cout << "lal->insert" << endl;
        if (index > size)
            return;

        //if we have no nodes to hold data make a new one between head and tail
        if (head->nextNode == tail)
        {
            linkNewNode(head, tail);
        }
        // lets find the node to put it in and the spot in the array of the node
        int indexIntoArray = 0;
        Node<ItemType>* temp = getNodeContainingIndex(index, indexIntoArray);
        if(temp->isFull())
        {
            // if we are full then we ant to split, and then call this function again to find the new location to go in.
            splitNode(temp);
            insert(index, item);
            return;
        }
        // and now insert it in
        cout << "lal->----attempting to add item at " << indexIntoArray << endl;
        temp->addItem(indexIntoArray, item);
        size ++;
    };

    Node<ItemType>* getNodeContainingIndex(int index, int& indexIntoArray)
    {
        cout << "lal->getNodeContainingIndex" << endl;
        Node<ItemType>* temp;
        if (index == size)
        {
            temp = tail->prevNode;
            indexIntoArray = temp->getSize();
        }
        else if (index <= (size/2)) /* coming from 0*/
        {
            cout << "lal->----coming from 0" << endl;
            int position = 0;
            temp = head->nextNode;
            position = position + temp->getSize();

            while (position < index)
            {
                temp = temp->nextNode;
                position = position + temp->getSize();
            }
            indexIntoArray = index - (position - temp->getSize());
            return temp;
        } 
        else /*coming from size*/
        {
            cout << "lal->----coming from size = " << size << endl;
            int position = size;
            temp = tail;
            while (position > index)
            {
                temp = temp->prevNode;
                position = position - temp->getSize();
            }
            indexIntoArray = abs(position - index);
            return temp;
        }
    }

    Node<ItemType>* linkNewNode(Node<ItemType>* prev, Node<ItemType>* next)
    {
        cout << "lal->linkNewNode" << endl;
        Node<ItemType>* temp = new Node<ItemType>(prev, next, arrayCapacity);
        prev->nextNode = temp; next->prevNode = temp;
        numOfNodes ++;
        return temp;
    }
```

it is in the getNodeContainingIndex function where it breaks, right here

```
int indexIntoArray = 0;
Node<ItemType>* temp = getNodeContainingIndex(index, indexIntoArray);
if(temp->isFull())
{
```

at the temp->isFull() line.

Comment: Are you using this class in a multi-threaded program? If so, that's most likely your problem. This class is not thread-safe.

Comment: Please, *please* do not write things like return `((getSize() >= capacity) ? true : false);`

Comment: no, it is a single thread, if it helps i can post the additional code of its linkedlist.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the constructor, and when you're there set another data breakpoint to go off when the value changes.

Comment: It could be a bad pointer that is doing rock'n'roll in your class' memory. Provide an example code that exhibits that behavior.

Comment: as for the ternary operator, it is proven to be faster then if else, and is plenty readable by me and my peers. Different people, different coding standards. however if that is the culprit then i will gladly change it.

Comment: `return (getSize() >= capacity)` is enough my dear friend. That expression already returns a boolean.

Comment: updated with the list class. thankyou for your helping :)

Comment: @m0skit0: `return getSize() >= capacity;` is also enough.

Comment: @KeithThompson Parenthesis hurt nobody ever.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I also sometimes put redundant parentheses around a boolean expression. It's a style thing, just looks cleaner to me somehow.

Comment: @WIllJBD that's way too long code to debug for me now. Hope someone else can lend a hand. I suggest you try yourself and find a shorter code that reproduces the problem so you can get more answers. Good luck!

Comment: You are dereferencing a NULL `Node` pointer. You can see that address is 0x00000004 and you call `getSize` which reads `size` member which is at 4-byte offset from beginning of `Node` struct. You need to break into `getNodeContainingIndex` code with debugger and see which instance exactly is the problem.

Comment: @m0skit0: The syntax of a return statement is `return expression ;`. IMHO, the parentheses make it look as if `return` is the name of a function (though the space before the `(` does alleviate that). But it's not a huge deal.

Comment: @KeithThompson see Mark Ransom answer. return cannot be a function since it's a reserved word. Anyway, **THIS** is a matter of style :)

Comment: This isn't really an integer changing its own value. It's a big chunk of code that (from your description) almost certainly contains some undefined behavior -- or maybe some of the other code you're using with it, but haven't shown does. Either way, at bare minimum you need to narrow the problem down quite a bit before it's reasonable to hope for others to debug it for you. Realistically, a debugger will probably do more good than we can.

Comment: @m0skit0: I know `return` can't *be* a function. My point is that adding parentheses makes it *look like* a function. Just curious, for a simple expression, do you write `return x;` or `return (x);`?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'd write `return x;` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is occurring because the pointer to the `LinkedArrayList` you are calling `isFull` on is null. I can tell this because you're getting an access violation at 0x00000004 error; and access violations with numbers that look like that are caused in this manner. The 4 is coming from the offset of `size` from the start of your object; the value of `size` meaningless because your pointer is junk.

It looks like there's a path through `getNodeContainingIndex` which does not return a value (where `index == size`); this could be causing your problem. But really you're best to step through in the debugger and see what it is doing.

Comment: thanks for the help, the culprit was indeed a missing path.

Comment: @WIllJBD That wasn't the culprit; it was a symptom. You need to ask yourself why, a few times, to get to the real culprit. You were trying to debug too much code, for one thing. Why have you null pointers in your code? Why have you few tests? etc.

Comment: Also, why did your compiler not pick up on this? Have you warnings turned down? So many you don't bother reading them? You should aim to have your code compiler with zero errors. Personally, I usually have 'treat warnings as errors' turned on but I accept this is not always possible.

Comment: if you must know, i have spent most my time in java, python, and objective c. I am very used to the eclipse and intelli-j way of things. Visual Studio is something I am still learning. The problem was the way I was going about searching the nodes from right to left and vice-versa. I needed to remove the path that returned a null pointer, then split 2 more paths, one from right and one from left, and finally set a recursive algorithm in each path to go through the nodes from the ends and find the correct position. So i replaced one function entirely, now it looks better and runs like a charm.